# Listening for Electron's ipcRenderer message inside a Vue component

Tags: event-handling, vuejs2, electron, vue-component

Currently, I'm using Vue inside an Electron application. Inside a Vue's master component there are possibly multiple children. Each child listens to a signal that might be broadcasted by Electron's main process, like so:

```
export default {
    ...
    created() {    
        ipcRenderer.on('set-service-status', (e, data) => {
            // something with the data
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

However when there are more than 11 child components, node throws the error `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 set-service-status listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`. This makes sense since multiple event listeners are being setup, one for every component.

How could this be solved? Should I just listen for the `set-service-status` signal inside the master component and then use Vue's eventing system to broadcast the message further down to the children? Or is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

as I understand the problem with your current setup is, your starting listening each time component created and this cause problem of having a lot of listeners for one `IPC` call.

instead of listening via `created()` put this logic inside of your `vuex`
and call it only once. or you can still use `created()` in your entry file, the main root component. and give the data to your child components as props. That also works.

for example;

```js
function setupIpc(dispatch) {
  ipcRenderer.on('set-service-status', (e, data) => {
        // something with the data
    })
  ipcRenderer.on('fullscreenChanged', (e, args) => {
    dispatch('fullscreenHandler', args)
  })
  ipcRenderer.send('ipcReady')
}
```

and only call once when you start the application,

```js
  updateState({ commit, dispatch }) {
    setupIpc(dispatch)
    setInterval(() => { dispatch('stateSaveImmediate') }, 5000)
    dispatch('init')
    ipcRenderer.once('configGet', (e, data) => {
      if (data === !null || !undefined) {
        commit(ActionTypes.UPDATE_STATE, data)
      } else {
        commit(ActionTypes.UPDATE_STATE_ERROR_NO_CONFIG_FILE)
      }
      dispatch('doSomething')
    })
    ipcRenderer.send('configGet')
  },
```

Comment: You're assuming that I'm using vuex as a state manager here. That's not the case. I only want to perform a visual update (display a loader) once the signal is received. If that involves introducing vuex that's fine but also creates slightly more complexity. There should be an easy way to do this without having to explicitly rely on a state manager no?

Comment: I just updated another way of doing, but it's kind a hacky way because in case of somehow if you `force update` the root component you will again start having multiple `ipcRenderer` message. you can check this via `Devtron` tool - IPC channel

Comment: I have actually been thinking myself about having one listener in the master component and have that one broadcast a vue event further down the children: `Vue.$root.$emit('set-service-status', componentId)`. And in the child component: `Vue.$root.$on('set-service-status', (id) => { // check if the component id matches the broadcasted id, then do something})`

Comment: do you have git repo which I can have look? giving it as props would be a better approach I guess.  unless your project requires something else.

Comment: hmm no, private repo unfortunately